# Can Ubuntu be installed from dos prompt

Tags: boot

I am new to Linux, just installed Ubuntu on desktop HP computer about 3 months ago and love it, still learning but much better than Windows 10.

I have a Nextbook 11 with windows 10 it had a fatal error and will not boot. No boot from USB is shown under boot options, I have tried to start using USB ISO file several times with no luck. I can get to dos prompt and was wondering if it is possible to install the Ubuntu ISO file from there. Any info is helpfully.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using a UEFI system. Make sure to format your USB as GPT for UEFI. I would use Rufus to burn the Ubuntu ISO. Note: You cannot boot/install Ubuntu from CMD.

Answer (score 3):

This is impossible. The Ubuntu ISO **must be booted from the BIOS or EFI system**.

Open another question about failure to boot the stick/DVD.

Comment: Is it possible to provide some links in your answer of duplicate questions for not being able to boot from USB? Chances are good a new question  will be flagged as duplicate anyway.

Comment: @RCarter do you use UEFI or BIOS to boot?